# What can I replace '.get_bloginfo('url').' with to return the current URL rather than the home address?

Tags: urls

I am using the [Any Mobile Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/) plugin to switch between full and mobile themes automatically.

The only problem with it is that the 'switch to mobile site' and 'switch to full site' links takes you to the home page instead of the current page.

The relevant bit of code seems to be this:

```
function show_theme_switch_link_func( $atts ){
        $desktopSwitchLink      = get_option('show_switch_link_for_desktop');
        global $shown_theme;
        global $status;
        if ($shown_theme){
                $return = '<a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'?am_force_theme_layout=desktop" class="am-switch-btn godesktop">'.get_option('desktop_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';
        } else {
                if ((!empty($status)) || ($desktopSwitchLink == 'yes')){
                        $return = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'?am_force_theme_layout=mobile" class="am-switch-btn gomobile">'.get_option('mobile_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';
                }
        }
        return $return;
}
```

Can I replace `'.get_bloginfo('url').'` with something that will return the current URL instead of the home address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20get%20current%20url) lead me to this little gem from a [blog post](http://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/) by Konstantin Kovshenin:

```
global $wp;
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

Combine that with your original code, and you have this (updated to match the WordPress coding standards):

```
function show_theme_switch_link_func( $atts ){
    global $shown_theme, $status, $wp;

    $desktop_switch_link = get_option( 'show_switch_link_for_desktop' );
    $current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );

    if ( $shown_theme ) {
        $return = '<a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="' . add_query_arg( 'am_force_theme_layout', 'desktop', $current_url ) . '" class="am-switch-btn godesktop">' . get_option( 'desktop_view_theme_link_text' ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        if ( !empty( $status ) || $desktop_switch_link == 'yes' ) {
            $return = '<a href="' . add_query_arg( 'am_force_theme_layout', 'mobile', $current_url ) . '" class="am-switch-btn gomobile">' . get_option( 'mobile_view_theme_link_text' ) . '</a>';
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear, your quite welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The code to display your current URL is:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>
```

So, for your code example, this should work:

```
function show_theme_switch_link_func( $atts ){
    $desktopSwitchLink      = get_option('show_switch_link_for_desktop');
    global $shown_theme;
    global $status;
    $currentURL = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if ($shown_theme){
            $return = '<a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="'.$currentURL.'?am_force_theme_layout=desktop" class="am-switch-btn godesktop">'.get_option('desktop_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';
    } else {
            if ((!empty($status)) || ($desktopSwitchLink == 'yes')){
                    $return = '<a href="'.$currentURL.'?am_force_theme_layout=mobile" class="am-switch-btn gomobile">'.get_option('mobile_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';
            }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Try that and see what happens...